# Trouble Updating a Table Row in Java

Tags: java, mysql, database

```
Connection conn = SqlConnection.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stocks");
Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

    File path = new File("/Users/Zack/Desktop/JavaDB/BALANCESHEETS");
    for(File file: path.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            String fileName = file.getName();
            String ticker = fileName.split("\\_")[0];
            if (ticker.equals("ASB") || ticker.equals("FRC")) {
                if (ticker.equals("ASB")) {
                    ticker = ticker + "PRD";
                }
                if (ticker.equals("FRC")) {
                    ticker = ticker + "PRD";
                }
            }

            //CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file));
            //List entries = reader.readAll();
            //ArrayList<String> entry = new ArrayList<String>();

            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            int c;
            while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
            builder.append((char) c);
            }

            String string = builder.toString();

            ArrayList<String> stringResult = new ArrayList<String>();

            if (string != null) {
                String[] splitData = string.split("\\s*,\\s*|\\n");
                for (int i = 0; i <splitData.length; i++) {
                    if (!(splitData[i] == null) || !(splitData[i].length() ==0)) {
                        stringResult.add(splitData[i].trim());
                    }
                }
            }

            String columnName = null;
            int yearCount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < stringResult.size(); i++) {
                int sL = stringResult.get(i).length();


                for (int x = 0; x < sL; x++) {
                    if (Character.isLetter(stringResult.get(i).charAt(x))) {
                        yearCount = 0;
                        System.out.println("index: " + i);
                        columnName = stringResult.get(i);
                        columnName = columnName.replace(" ", "_");
                        System.out.println(columnName);

                        i++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                yearCount++;
                String value = stringResult.get(i);
                System.out.println("Year: " + stringResult.get(yearCount) + " Value: " + value + " Stock: " + ticker + " Column: " + columnName );
                if (!(columnName == null)) {
                String writeValues = "INSERT INTO BalanceSheet (ticker, Year, " + columnName + ") "
                                    + "VALUE ('" + ticker + "','" + stringResult.get(yearCount) + "','" + value + "')";
                String writeValues2 = "UPDATE BalanceSheet "
                                    + "SET ticker = '" + ticker + "', " 
                                        + "Year = '" + stringResult.get(yearCount) + "', "
                                        + columnName + " = '" + value + "' "
                                        + "WHERE ticker = '" + ticker + "'";
                statement.executeUpdate(writeValues2);
                }
            }
```

Towards the bottom of the code are two queries I tried, I'm trying to get all data organized by ticker and year into a table, "writeColumns" works but it's making a new row for every new "value" put into "columnName". My second attempt "writeColumns2" doesn't do anything.

I want to update the same row with a certain year for all values and then move onto the next year, then next ticker.

Comment: First off - use `PreparedStatement`. Second, check what are the values coming in the variables `columnName`, `ticker`, `yearCount`? Is there any row present in database for the passed `ticker`?

Comment: is this sorted out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, you want to insert a row if it doesn't exists but update the values if it already does. You need to use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

```
String writeValues = "INSERT INTO BalanceSheet (ticker, Year, " + columnName + ") "
                                    + "VALUES (?,?,?) "
        +"ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " + columnName +"=?";

Statement statement = conn.prepareStatement(writeValues);
statement.setString(1,ticker);
statement.setString(2,stringResult.get(yearCount));
statement.setString(3, value);
```

This will solve your immidiate problem provided you create a UNIQUE index on ticker,year

However there are lot's of other issues here.

**An update for each column** - Currently you are doing an insert/update for each column on the table. What you are supposed to do is to insert update all the columns at one.

**You are not using prepared statements** addressed in my code sample

**You shouldn't be doing this at all** the best way to batch process data is to use MYSQL's built in LOAD DATA INFILE command. If your data is not in a format that can be easily imported into mysql, what your Java code can do is to transform it into a format that can be. Such a code will be a lot simpler and neater than what you have now

Comment: Hey, I appreciate you answering, for some reason I couldn't figure out how to implement your solution, I understand I should use prepared statements and I should fix that.

Comment: But, my assignment was to parse csv files using java and update my database, I didn't realize I could use LOAD DATA INFILE to solve this. I did find a solution however, and it looks very sloppy to me but it worked. I updated my post with how I solved it.

Comment: 1) you've probably got a lousy lecturer.  2) bad form to edit a question after a valid answer has been recieved. 3) if you want to post your own solution, you can add your own answer and later accept it. 4) if the solultion you found is sloppy don't use it. As a beginner the worst thing to do is to get into these bad habits.